# Trying to get property of non-object in PHP LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

im new in laravel and programming i want to insert in Isilowongan table but i cant, i already search the internet and fix my database buat i still cant can you help me?

controller :

```
public function isiLowongan($id)
{
    $lowongan = Reqlowongan::find($id);
    return view('mahasiswa/isi_lowongan', compact(['lowongan']));
}
public function addIsilowongan(Request $req, $id)
{
    $lowongan = Reqlowongan::find($id);
    $lowongan = new Isilowongan;
    $lowongan ->mahasiswa_id = auth()->user()->mahasiswa->id;
    $lowongan ->reqlowongan_id = $req->input('reqlowongan_id');
    $lowongan ->ipk = $req->input('ipk');
    $lowongan ->agama = $req->input('agama');
    $lowongan ->semester = $req->input('semester');
    $lowongan ->prodi = $req->input('prodi');
    $lowongan ->save();
    return redirect('index')->with('status', 'Terimakasih Sudah Mendaftar!');
}
```

this is my database
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YECW7.png)

this is my error:

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

and this is thhe problem
[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X57M.png)

[image]

mahasiswa model

```
public function isilowongan()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Isilowongan::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Reqlowongan model

```
 protected $table="req_lowongan";
protected $fillable=['jenis_lowongan', 'ipk', 'agama', 'semester', 'prodi'];

public function instansi()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Instansi::class);
}

public function isilowongan()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Isilowongan::class);
}
```

Isilowongan model

```
 protected $table="isi_lowongan";
protected $fillable=['mahasiswa_id', 'reqlowongan_id','ipk', 'agama', 'semester', 'prodi'];

public function mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Mahasiswa::class);
}

public function reqlowongan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Reqlowongan::class);
}

public function status()
{
    $isilow = $this->all();
    $text = null;

    if($this->ipk >= $this->reqlowongan->ipk AND
    $this->agama == $this->reqlowongan->agama AND 
    $this->semester == $this->reqlowongan->semester AND
    $this->prodi == $this->reqlowongan->prodi){
        $text = 'LOLOS';
        return $text;
    }else{
        $text = 'TIDAK LOLOS';
        return $text;
    }
}
```

user Model

```
protected $table='users';
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function mahasiswa() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Mahasiswa::class);
}

public function karyawan() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Karyawan::class);
}

public function instansi() 
{
    return $this->hasOne(Instansi::class);
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error message and point out the line where it happens.

Comment: ok sorry, i already the error message and where is the error

Comment: Dump `auth()->user()` and see what it contains. The error message is telling you that `auth()->user()->mahasiswa` is not an object.

Comment: No, not delete, [dump](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump). Dumping is a method of displaying all the details of a variable.

Comment: is this how to use it? $lowongan ->mahasiswa_id = dump(auth()->user()->mahasiswa->id);

Comment: `var_dump(auth()->user());` or `dd(auth()->user());`

Comment: No, don't do it inside the assignment. Put that on a different line before the one that causes the error.

Comment: that is the result at the top (screenshot), i put 'dd(auth()->user());' before '$lowongan ->mahasiswa_id = auth()->user()->mahasiswa->id;'

Comment: try `dd(auth()->user()->mahasiswa)` and check  you must have `User::class` inside this function `mahasiswa()` this function

Comment: it says null when i try it, and i give my model at top maybe its wrong

Answer (score 1):

You seem to overwrite your variable $lowongan right after you've assigned data to it:

```
$lowongan = Reqlowongan::find($id);
$lowongan = new Isilowongan;
```

That doesn't make sense. According to your Model Reqlowongan, you dont have a direct relation to Mahasiswa, so I assume you want to use the mahasiswa_id of the currently logged in user:

put

```
use Auth;
```

before

```
class YourController extends Controller {}
```

then you can access the mahasiswa_id like so:

```
Auth::user()->mahasiswa()->id;
```

Full example:

```
use Auth;

class YourController extends Controller {

 public function addIsilowongan(Request $req, $id)
 {
  // $lowongan = Reqlowongan::find($id); // you dont use that
  // sidenote: $id would be the same as $req->input('reqlowongan_id')
  $lowongan = new Isilowongan;
  $lowongan->mahasiswa_id = Auth::user()->mahasiswa()->id;
  $lowongan->reqlowongan_id = $req->input('reqlowongan_id');
  $lowongan->ipk = $req->input('ipk');
  $lowongan->agama = $req->input('agama');
  $lowongan->semester = $req->input('semester');
  $lowongan->prodi = $req->input('prodi');
  $lowongan->save();

  return redirect('index')->with('status', 'Terimakasih Sudah Mendaftar!');
 }
}
```